# C# Radiobutton oncheckchanged not firing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a radiobutton control dynamically generated inside of a repeater. On this radiobutton I am calling `OnCheckChanged` to change some value in the code behind on checking on the radiobutton.

```
<EclipseUI:CustomRadioButton ID="RadioButton_Selected" runat="server" GroupName='<%# "s_id_" + Eval("FeaturePackId") %>' 
 OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_Selected_OnCheckedChanged"/>
```

My Radiobuttonis above and calls the shown method.

If it makes any difference the radiobutton is being checked and unchecked by jquery code on a div click.

```
protected void RadioButton_Selected_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomRadioButton rb = (CustomRadioButton) sender;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rb.GroupName);
    int FeatureID = Int32.Parse(rb.GroupName.Remove(0, 4));

    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        FeatureList.Add(FeatureID);
    }
    if (!rb.Checked)
    {
        foreach (var itemToRemove in FeatureList)
        {
            FeatureList.Remove(itemToRemove);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(itemToRemove);
        }
    }
}

public List<int> FeatureList = new List<int>();
```

This code basically adds of subsracts the value on the radiobuttonto the List of ints. However this method is not being called at all. I have tried placing the debug writeline statements but these do not output anything to the output window.

Does anyone know why this method is not firing?

Comment: I think you  missing AutoPostback="True" property in redio button .

Comment: @NayeemMansoori I've tried adding `AutoPostback="True"` but the debug writeline still does not fire or the method not called as far as i am aware etc

Comment: Show your jquery code that is "clicking" the radiobutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first because its easy.

Similar question here:
[OnCheckedChanged event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596767/oncheckedchanged-event-not-firing)

There are two differences from the posted answer to yours:
Enabled="true"
AutoPostBack="true"

But since you tried this already I really think it is more likely because you are creating your elements in the wrong place in the page lifecycle (timewise too early) at the pre-page rendering so you may want to create the method binding in the pageload in the non-postback.

In short you have the method and the button but they are not bound to each other.

I am not sure this code will work 'as is', but it might give you some ideas.

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
         CustomRadioButton rb = (CustomRadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("CustomRadioButtonID");
         rb.OnCheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButton_Selected_OnCheckedChanged);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should set the PostBack property to TRUE on your CustomRadioButton control.